# link_to expecting keyword_end rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i don't understand why but i still have a problem when following the ruby on rails tutorial. It's when you put the links on to navigate between the different page..

this is my view:

```
<h1>New Article</h1>
<%= form_for @article, url: articles_path do |f| %> <!<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %> >

  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this article from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>

<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

and this is my controller

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new' #on utilise render car cela permet de recharger la requête d'article
                  #qui vient d'échouer contrairement à redirect_to qui lancerais une nouvelle requete
    end
  end

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def edit
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
  end

  def destroy
  end
end

private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
  end
```

if you need some over tell me.

So if you have any tips, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Its not the `link` that is expecting `end` keyword. The actual error is due to no `end` tag to the form.
Please update yours as below

```
<h1>New Article</h1>
<%= form_for @article, url: articles_path do |f| %> <!<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %> >

  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this article from being saved:
      </h2>
        <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <ul>
              <li><%= msg %></li>
          </ul>
        <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<%end%>
<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your quick answer, and i did what you told me to do. In fact I missed the end in the form. But now a new error comes which points the "heading" line 2:

Error message:
"First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty"

The new code

```
 <h1>New Article</h1>
<%= form_for @article url: articles_path  do |f| %>

  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this article from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>

<%end%>

<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

Can you find the bug. I would like to improve myself in Ruby and Ror.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Try this
<%= form_for(@article, url: articles_path)  do |f| %>

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not initialized your @article variable in the new action.
In your new action write it as `@article = Article.new`and it should work fine.
As you have not initialized @article, it gives you a nil value error in the form.

Comment: Hi i didn't see your answer before i resposted a question.
So i did what you tell me to and it works. In fact i missed to declare it in the new action.

Thank you for your answer and your support 

Have a good day